# How do I use zip print on a list of strings in python without it returning with quotations surrounding them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace, python-zip

Current code:

```py
reps = ['x 5', 'x 5', 'x 3', 'x 5', 'x 5', 'x 5+']
b = [90, 122, 135, 146, 168, 191]

print(str(list(zip(b,reps))).replace(',',''))
```

here is the current output:

`[(90 'x 5') (112 'x 5') (135 'x 3') (146 'x 5') (168 'x 5') (191 'x 5+')]`

here is my goal output:

`[(90 x 5) (112 x 5) (135 x 3) (146 x 5) (168 x 5) (191 x 5+)]`

How would I remove those single quotes?

I tried using replace but I'm not sure how to both replace the commas separating the weight and the reps, as well as the quotations around the rep range.

I also tried replacing the quotations in the list reps on a separate line of code but once it is printed within the zip they were added back.

Comment: `[f"{x} {y}" for x, y in zip(b, reps)]`, using `f-strings` to concatenate each element in `b` and `reps`

Comment: `(90 x 5)` makes no sense in Python, not even when `x` is defined.

Comment: As no_hex implies it has to be a string "90 x 5" which is why @tidakdiinginkan
 gives a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like *cosmetic* output, but the following will work for your case:

```
print('[' + ' '.join(f"({x} {y})" for x, y in zip(b, reps)) + ']')
```

---

```
[(90 x 5) (122 x 5) (135 x 3) (146 x 5) (168 x 5) (191 x 5+)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a thing of beauty, but if your only goal is to end up with exactly the output you specified then this will do that:

```
reps = ['x 5', 'x 5', 'x 3', 'x 5', 'x 5', 'x 5+'] 
b = [90, 122, 135, 146, 168, 191]

# creates a list of strings of the form: "(X x Y)"
arr = [f"({y} {x})" for x, y in zip(reps, b)]

# prints the list as a single string surrounded by brackets
print(f"[{' '.join(arr)}]")
```

Output:

```
[(90 x 5) (122 x 5) (135 x 3) (146 x 5) (168 x 5) (191 x 5+)]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want that exact format you can use

```py
print(
    str(list(map(lambda tup: f"({str(tup[0])} {tup[1]})",list(zip(b,reps))))).replace("'",'').replace(",",'')
)

print(str([f"({x} {y})" for x, y in zip(b, reps)]).replace(",", "").replace("'",""))
```

Maybe is not the most efficient way, but it works